# License management database for 3rd party software components

Tags: software-development, legal

We're a software vendor, and we search a license management database for the 3rd party components we include in our product.

We want to use this tool to structure our existing "loose leaf collection", so we gain structure, searchability, and similar features.

We need to manage a structure like 4 tables and corresponding relations:

1. Product
2. Component
3. 3rd-party component
4. License

Each product consists of one or several components, and a component may be included in several products. 3rd-Party components may include other 3rd party components.

A real-world example is: Our product "CODESYS SVN" has (amongst others) a component "SVN Plugin", which links dynamically against SharpSVN. SharpSVN is under Apache license, but includes (links statically) other components like SVN (Apache license), Neon (GPL), zlib (zlib License) etc.

Versioning of components and dependencies is also helpful (e. G. newer SVN versions did drop the Neon library in favour of Serf).

Bonus points for multi-user software (e. G. Web-App), but this is not a strict must (we could also use terminal server etc.).

The Software should be hosted in-house - due to contractual requirements, we cannot send such kind of information to some system which is hosted externally. Our company ist mainly windows centric, but we also have linux machines in our server infrastructure, and remote login is acceptable for the intended audience, so we have full flexibility on this side.

We're open for free and commercial software, and we don't have a fixed budget (we're just evaluating the options).

My own research mostly pointed to software assisting with license management for the software one *uses* in the company (number installed MS office licenses etc.), so either I've got the wrong search terms (no native speaker), or such beasts are hard to find.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: I'm not versed enough in the product to be confident that it is a solution, but sonatype at least offers solutions close to this domain. http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/product-overview

Comment: It seems that this is more a repository for storing the actual components, instead of management of metadata. However, I'll have a closer look at it soon.